# Try catch exception for factorial recursion function

Tags: java, methods, try-catch

I want my factorial to output a statement printing out "invalid error. No negative numbers" when I incorporate a try -catch method but everytime it doesn't print my error statement. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value;
   //E.g. 4!=4*3*2*1
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a value for factorial");
    value=keyboard.nextInt();
    try{
    System.out.println(calculate(value));}catch(NumberFormatException e){

        System.out.println("invalid error. No negative numbers");

    }

}

private static int calculate(int value){


    if(value==1 || value==0){
        return 1;
    }
    return  calculate(value-1)*value;

}

}
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Why do you expect the call to `System.out.println(calculate(value))` to throw a `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: You're probably getting a negative number because of an overflow.  factorials get big fast, and when the value is too big for an 'int', it overflows and becomes negative

Answer (score 5):

You haven't thrown the Exception

```
private static int calculate(int value) throws NumberFormatException {

    if (value < 0) throw new NumberFormatException("invalid error. No negative numbers");
    if(value==1 || value==0){
        return 1;
    }
    return  calculate(value-1)*value;

}
```

Comment: `NumberFormatException` is for parsing strings. You should be using an `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: @4castle I agree with this comment, but OP specified NFE. You should post your comment to OP